# What is the width of empty space in HTML?

Tags: html, css

For example,

```
<a>foo</a>
<a>bar</a>
```

And CSS

```
a {
    background-color:red;
}
```

There will be a white space between the `a`, what is the width?

Comment: Depends on lots of stuff. Have you tried anything

Comment: Precisely what @EdHeal said. For instance, this fiddle works with -5px for me.

Comment: Its because `<a>` is a inline element, by default there are spaces between them. If you want too remove them, check: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: That is one part. How about the `position` parameter.

Comment: @web-tiki, Jrn: Exactly what was in my mind when I posted my original comment (which I have removed now because it caused more misunderstanding). But as another user (I think Amadan) commented, if we set `font-size: 30px` on the body, the margin width is increasing. [Sample with font-size](http://jsfiddle.net/M6vRj/1/)

Comment: @Harry you are right, `word-spacing` on the parent also changes the width of the white-space : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/HPjVE/

Comment: There are two easy ways to eliminate whitespace between two elements: 1) remove the inter-element whitespace from the HTML manually 2) don't use inline-blocks in the first place. The whole point of inline-blocks is that they need to flow inline, just like any other text. That is why spaces affect them the way they do.

Answer (score 15):

The width is the advance width of the common SPACE U+0020 character. This width varies by font; according to Microsoft’s [Space Characters Design Standards](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/developers/fdsspec/spaces.htm), it may vary from 0.2em to 0.5em, and the typical width is 0.25em. Here, as usual, em denotes the size of the font. Thus, if the font size is 16px, a typical spacing would be 4px, but the spacing may vary from 3px to 8px, depending on font.

The reason is that when there is (only) whitespace between two inline elements, like a line break in this case, one SPACE character is rendered between them. (This applies under normal conditions. If `text-align: justify` is in effect, the space may be stretched.)

Normally should not worry about the width, but you may have some specific reason for knowing it, e.g. in order to cancel its effect by setting a negative margin with the same value. However, if you want to remove the spacing, the simplest and most robust method is to remove all whitespace between the elements: `<a>foo</a><a>bar</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Default if the anchor tags are written in a single line it would not take any space but when it is written in two lines you will press an enter which seems to take 1 character or 2 character width

Answer (score 0):

## What it is

Depends upon the font family / font size. It is rendered **as a single space** (and that is the width) because of the way multiple spaces become one space in `white-space: normal` style tags.

## How to fix it

To fix it just set the font size of the parent to zero and an explicit size of the child e.g.

```
a {
    background-color:red;
    font-size: 15px;
}
body{
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/K2WAn/

This has issues with `em` since those cascade so there are other fixes as well : http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: but this solution fails if we change the unit from `px` to `em`. How to fix this issue in that case?

Comment: @KheemaPandey updated to split between *answer the question* + possible fixes

Comment: so there is exactly no solution if using font size in `em`.

Comment: Use rems if you want them